# Merge lines after specific word till another specific word in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, line

I have been trying to combine lines from a specific word to another specific word:

```
EOD++::N'
GSM
+
38
+
38
+
32
+
1
'
USF+1+ABCDEFGH'
```

The output should be:

```
EOD++::N'
GSM+38+38+32+1'
USF+1+ABCDEFGH'
```

I tried to merge lines using regex   `(\+)\n([0-9]{1,2})\n)` but no luck. A help is appreciated :)

Comment: You could prepend an optional newline `\R?(\+)\R([0-9]{1,2})\R` https://regex101.com/r/GaVuD9/1

Comment: And what are the words? Your `(\+)\n([0-9]{1,2})\n)` pattern has no words.

Comment: I'm sorry if you were confused. I just wanted to merge from GSM to till '
the final result should be GSM+38+38+32+1' without messing up the previous line or next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all consecutive matches after matching `GSM` at the start of the string using the `\G` anchor. You keep the values in the capturing group, and match a newline in between so that they are not part of the replacement.

**Find what:**

```
(?:^GSM\K\R(?=[\r\n+0-9]+\R')|\G)(\+)\R([0-9]{1,2})\R
```

**Replace with:**

```
$1$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1Dqvw/1)

[image]

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^GSM\K\R` Match GSM, then `\K` will forget what is currently matched and then match the newline
  - `(?=[\r\n+0-9]+\R')` Positive lookahead, assert that what follows are the allowed characters, newline `'`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start
- `)` Close group
- `(\+)` Capture **group 1**, match +
- `\R` Match the newline after it
- `([0-9]{1,2})` Capture **group 2**, match 1-2 digits
- `\R` Match the newline after it

Answer (score -1):

```
^(.*[^'])(\n)
```

For your example this will work.

Comment: Your solution does not meet the requirements outlined in the question, namely *combine lines **from a specific word to another specific word***